# Send PDF to Azure Function Business Central

Tags: azure, azure-functions, dynamics-business-central

I am trying to create azure function which will take PDF, sent from BC and encrypted it with password.

```
pdftext := Base64Convert.ToBase64(Instr);

DictionaryL.Add('name', pdftext);

Respons := AzureFunctions.SendGetRequest(Auth, DictionaryL);
if Respons.IsSuccessful() then
  message('Successful')
else
  message(Respons.GetError());

Respons.GetResultAsTExt(Result);
message(Result);
```

I try two different approach.
First, to send instream from BC with content

```
 public static class PdfFunction
   {
       [FunctionName("PdfFunction")]
       public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
           [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req)
       {
            
           //// Retrieve the PDF file from the request body
           using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               await req.Body.CopyToAsync(stream);

               // Encrypt the PDF file
               byte[] encryptedPdf = EncryptPdf(stream, "passwordtest111");

               // Return the encrypted PDF file
               return new FileContentResult(encryptedPdf, "application/pdf")
               {
                   FileDownloadName = "encrypted.pdf"
               };
           }
       }
       private static byte[] EncryptPdf(Stream inputPdfStream, string password)
       {
           using (var outputPdfStream = new MemoryStream())
           {
               var reader = new PdfReader(inputPdfStream);
               var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outputPdfStream);
               stamper.SetEncryption(
                   PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128, // Encryption algorithm
                   password, // Password
                   password, // Owner password
                   PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING); // Permissions
               stamper.Close();
               reader.Close();

               return outputPdfStream.ToArray();
           }
       }
   }
```

And azure function is like down there, but always got an error. Seams like I don't take stream parameter on azure function correct.

I also try to convert pdf to ToBase64, and send it like dictionary parameter but got error

```
   DictionaryL.Add('name', pdftext);

   Respons := AzureFunctions.SendGetRequest(Auth, DictionaryL);
   if Respons.IsSuccessful() then
   message('Successful')
   else
   message(Respons.GetError());

   Respons.GetResultAsTExt(Result);
   message(Result);
```

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)